# When dealing with GD Library unwantedly altering colors

Tags: php, image, gdlib

I'm merging multiple small images into a rectangular mosaic.

When dealing with a small number of source images it turns out fine:

[image]

But when dealing with a larger number of sources it turns out a sepia like effect:

[image]

Is there any technique I should be used to preserve the colors?

My method for merging the images is essentially running a script that loops through the source images using `imagecreatefromjpeg()` to grab it, followed by `imagecopy()` to merge the source onto the collective destination image (and runs until all images have been added/placed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of using imagecreate() as my starting point, I changed to imagecreatetruecolor() and it has resolve the color loss issue.